# Events Payment - quirky scenario

Tags: civievent, paylater

Can anyone assist with the following scenario please...

Our organisation conducts training events, the fees for which are calculated at a fixed price per trainer - not by the number of students that attend. So regardless of whether or not 10 or 25 students attend, the fee is the same, which is actually not paid by the students themselves but rather a 3rd party organisation after the event is completed.

It may be worth noting that we are using CiviCRM as more of a historical database as opposed to a online registration/payment system, and generally all data (contacts and event) will be entered manually after an event takes place.

As I am typing this I am thinking that perhaps a manual (gulp!) workaround is to just divide the event fee by the actual number of students that attended the event and set this as the event amount when the data entry is taking place....?

So I'm not sure how best to configure an event to allow for $0 to be paid by the student, but I'd like to see a $ value for the overall event a summary report somehow.

Make sense? Is this possible to do?

Thanks, Joe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out what you can achieve by using the Batch Update by Profile process.

Create a Profile that has the Fee Amount field for Participants.

Go to Find Participants. Search for those that attended your event. Under Actions click on Batch Update by Profile.

You should then be able to enter the required amount for the top row, and use the 'photocopy' icon above the Fee Amount column to apply that to all Participants.

If you want to record the 'total cost' of the event you could also look at adding a Custom Field on to Events and use that to record the total cost of the event.

Comment: Thanks.I'll go with the "If you want to record the 'total cost' of the event you could also look at adding a Custom Field on to Events and use that to record the total cost of the event." approach.

Comment: cool - would be good if you can +1 the answer as well as 'accepting' it as it is the +s that float the best answer to the top

Answer (score 0):

To My understanding -

Yes you can create an Event with Zero amount -

Create an Event First - In the Fees section - select Paid Event - Yes

Only select Enable Pay Later option?

In the Regulat Fees set the Fee Label and Amount as 0.00 as default

this will allow you to create a fee amount of Zero

Also you have an option of selecting Multiple participants upto 10 but still you will find only one contribution against the first contact

Also for the report - Go to Event Participants List and select all the participant based on the event

you can list all the members registered for this event which you can export to CSV

I guess this helps !!!